# Firefox 3.6.8 uninstall keeps telling me to restart my computer

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

Been trying to uninstall Firefox 3.6.8 from XP SP3 (3.6.6 seems to be there too), but receiving "Your computer must be restarted to complete a previous upgrade of Firefox. Do you want to reboot now?" message.

Followed the instructions,

https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Uninstalling+Firefox

but uninstaller is repeating it's mantra "Your computer must be restarted..."

Just want to get rid of FF.  Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you've tried rebooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [I keep getting this message “your computer must be restarted to complete a previous uninstall of firefox” ?](http://www.seasonsecurity.com/i-keep-getting-this-message-your-computer-must-be-restarted-to-complete-a-previous-uninstall-of-firefox-75686)

> rename file C:\Program Files\Mozilla
>   Firefox\firefox.exe.moz-delete to
>   firefox.exe.moz-delete.old and the
>   installer will work, if you rename or
>   remove the complete folder you will
>   also loose all your settings and
>   plugins
>
> I had to rename the file called
>   C:\Program Files\Mozilla
>   Firefox\firefox.exe.moz-upgrade to
>   firefox.exe.moz-upgrade.old for it to
>   work, but it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try force-uninstalling it with [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)?